# Register types from Assembly in Windsor Castle with 'where' predicate

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am puzzled at how to implement registration that satisfy the following conditions:

1. From current assembly
2. public + non public types
3. The same namespace as TInterface
4. All services and Self
5. The type should end with 'adapter'

I use the following method, but I don't understand where put 'where' type is clause:

```
private BasedOnDescriptor CreateDescriptor<TInterface>(Predicate<Type> accepted)
{
   return Classes
       .FromAssemblyContaining<TInterface>()
       .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
       .Where(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<TInterface>())
       .WithService.AllInterfaces()
       .WithService.Self();
}
```

The 'accepted' clause should point what type name should be used
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Adapter"))`

However, putting the *how* aside, it might be a good idea to separate the types into their own namespace, for architectural clarity. The sideeffect being, you wouldn't need the extra filter predicate.

Comment: Thank you! The types are indeed in the same namespace, but the namespace includes some other type, besides, I don't own these types, because they are autogenerated and from ado.net ))

Comment: Somehow weird that there is diffrenent semantic between 'where' and 'if'. It would be transparent if 'where' was fluent allowing to chain configuring.

Comment: Can I use OnCreate for BasedOnDescriptor?

Comment: @Dmitry `.Configure(x=>x.OnCreate())`

Comment: This 'OnCreate' for BasedOnDescriptor has signature: OnCreate(params Action<object>[] actions) what is why I had to filter all adapters before using this 'Configure'. Thank you for response.